# MariaDB memory much higher than innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: linux, mysql, httpd, mariadb, oom

I have a backend server with **1G RAM** for my HTTP server and my MariaDB.

I noticed the database keeps getting killed by OOM once or twice a day. Most of the time the OOM is triggered by the HTTP server, but not always.

I tried limiting **innodb_buffer_pool_size** many times, it is at **64M** at this moment, but the process is still taking 40% to 60% of the server's memory.

How do I find the reason of this memory usage? It appears to be some kind of memory leak, because it keeps increasing throughout the day.

The database usually starts consuming about 7% to 9% of memory usage.

MariaDB version 10.5

Comment: Have you made any other changes to the configuration?  Please provide the `GLOBAL STATUS` and `VARIABLES` so we can look for other things to shrink.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning .  I do not want to shrink the buffer_pool_size; it is already dangerously low.  Can you turn on "swapping"; that may prevent the OOM killer.  (or it may cause worse problems.)

Comment: (This belongs in dba.stackexchange.com please migrate it.)